# Asymptotic behaviour of e * !n - n! , n tends to infinity

Tags: asymptotics

What is the asymptotic behaviour of the function $e !n-n!$ , where 
 $!n = n! \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ is the subfactorial of $n$. I tried 
 Wolfram Alpha but the series for n=$\infty$ is pretty complicated. There should be
 a simplier function doing the job.

The function arises from the integrals

$\int_{0}^{1}e^xx^ndx$ = $(-1)^n(e !n-n!)$  for every positive integer $n$.

Comment: Hint: Start by writing $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} = \frac{1}{e} - \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.$$

Comment: The taylor series of $e^{-1}$ was also my first thought.

Comment: Totally.  Let me know if you need more guidance.

Comment: I still do not see the solution.

Comment: A moment, is it $\frac {e}{n+1}$ ?

Comment: Actually, I just reread your post and I realized I'm taking you in the wrong direction.  It's much easier to find the asymptotics directly from the integral $\int_0^1 e^x x^n\,dx$ using, say, [Watson's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson's_lemma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to work directly with the integral

$$
I(n) = \int_0^1 e^x x^n\, dx.
$$

Make the substitution $x = e^{-t}$ to put it into the form

$$
I(n) = \int_0^\infty e^{e^{-t}-t} e^{-nt} \,dt.
$$

Watson's lemma tells us that we can expand the integrand as a power series about $t=0$

$$
e^{e^{-t}-t} = e-2 e t+\frac{5 e t^2}{2} + \cdots
$$

and integrate term-by-term to obtain an asymptotic expansion for the integral.  Thus

$$
\begin{align}
I(n) &\approx e \int_0^\infty e^{-nt}\,dt - 2e \int_0^\infty te^{-nt}\,dt + \frac{5e}{2} \int_0^\infty t^2 e^{-nt}\,dt + \cdots \\
&= \frac{e}{n} - \frac{2 e}{n^2} + \frac{5 e}{n^3} + \cdots.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I found an even easier way which only gives $\frac{e}{n}$ : By integration by parts, it is easy to check I(k)=e-k*I(k-1). I(k) is a positive and decreasing function. So 0<I(k)=e-k*I(k-1)<I(k-1). It follows immediately $\frac{e}{k+1}$<I(k-1)<$\frac{e}{k}$ and therefore $\frac{e}{k+2}$<I(k)<$\frac{e}{k+1}$. So, $\frac{e}{k}$ is an asymptote.

Comment: But since your formula shows better bounds, I vote it up.